# Using Ninject contexts to create context-dependent singletons and factories

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

**The Background**

I have a 'root' instance that implements IEnvironment. In my application, there might be multiple ([1..N]) IEnvironments. Each environment contains a bunch of objects, some of them containing ninject factories, others are singletons (Bind<...>().To<...>.InSingletonScope()).

I implemented a prototype with a single IEnvironment that simply uses default bindings, all the dependent objects get their single instances passed in, the factories are created using the Ninject ToFactory() extensions. This works.

I use ctor-injection almost exclusively, and I would prefer to keep it that way.

**The Goal**

How do I make a different context for each environment? That is, each of the instances in IEnvironment should get same ISingleton, and all factories in those objects should pass this singleton to it's created objects, but every IEnvironment should have a different ISingleton instance.

**The Problem**

I have read the articles about Ninject's [Contextual Binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) and [Context Preservation](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/12/08/ninject-extension-contextpreservation-explained/). But I do not understand how to map this to my problem. As far as I understand, I cannot use named bindings or attributes, since I can potentially have N IEnvironments, and that number might be dependent on some information passed on from outside.

So - how do I have to set up Ninject or my app to get this to work? I am looking for an answer that explains a conceptual approach on how to solve this.

Comment: It's not Singleton if there are multiple instances. But i think i get what you mean. You should look into other scoped bindings of ninject, like .InNamedScope(). However, you will most likely have to create a custom scope or create the object "manually" when creating the context, and then putting it on the context by using an argument (Constructor-Argument,...). If you can provide your (simple) prototype implementation i could give you more specific pointers. Also see: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes

Comment: Question: In Addition to the multiple instances of ISingleton, should there also be different implementations of ISingleton?

Comment: No, all should be the same. It's multiple identical processes that are modelled.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I read up on the Object-Scopes and the linked extensions in there - it's exactly what I need. Feel free to make an answer out of your comment for me to accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meet the following conditions you can use `.InNamedScope(...)`:

- an environment does not create another environment
- `ISingleton` is not used outside of an environment (i.E. only injected into environment or into a dependency of of environment which is instanciated for every environment).

Remark: If you want to resolve a new object which uses an `ISingleton` by a factory inside your environment, then you will need to use context preservation extension.

```
this.Bind<IEnvironment>().To<Environment>().DefinesNamedScope("SomeName");
this.Bind<ISingleton>().To<Singleton>.InNamedScope("SomeName")
```

--> Ensures only one Singleton instance is created in the environment request scope.

*And of course you can also create your own `InScope(...)` if this would suit your needs better.*

**Another alternative** is using an inherited constructor argument (again, use context preservation if you need to preserve the context when creating an instance at a later time):

```
IEnvironment CreateEnvironment()
{
  var singleton = IResolutionRoot.Get<ISingleton>();
  return IResolutionRoot.Get<IEnvironment>(new ConstructorArgument("singleton", singleton, true);
}
```

Hint: The constructor argument takes parameter shouldInherit which should be true in this case.
I also suggest to use a different parameter than ConstructorArgument. With ConstructorArgument the parameter name needs to match (i.e. when some class wants to have ISingleton injected, it needs to have a ctor parameter named "singleton).
This would be an alternative:

public class TypedConstructorArgument : ITypedParameter, IConstructorArgument
    {
        public TypedConstructorArgument(Type argumentType, object argumentValue)
            : this(argumentType, argumentValue, false)
        {
        }

```
    public TypedConstructorArgument(Type argumentType, object argumentValue, bool shouldInherit)
    {
        Ensure.ArgumentAssignableFrom(argumentType, argumentValue, "argumentValue");

        this.ArgumentType = argumentType;
        this.ArgumentValue = argumentValue;
        this.ShouldInherit = shouldInherit;

        this.Name = argumentType.FullName;
    }

    public virtual string Name { get; private set; }

    public virtual bool ShouldInherit { get; private set; }

    public virtual Type ArgumentType { get; private set; }

    public virtual object ArgumentValue { get; private set; }

    public object GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target)
    {
        return this.ArgumentValue;
    }

    public bool AppliesToTarget(IContext context, ITarget target)
    {
        return this.MatchesType(target.Type);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as IParameter;
        return other != null && this.Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.GetType().GetHashCode() ^ this.Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(IParameter other)
    {
        return other.GetType() == this.GetType() && other.Name.Equals(this.Name);
    }

    public bool MatchesType(Type type)
    {
        return this.ArgumentType == type;
    }
}
```

Comment: I use InNamedScope now, it's comparatively simple and does exactly what I need.